# Flutter: why can my function never be null?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a function to query Firestore. If it finds a record, it should return the doc ID of that record as a `string`. If it finds no records, then it should return `null`. However, when I check the result of this function somewhere else, it gives a warning that the result can never be null. Why is this? I want the function to either return the doc ID or a `null`, but if there is a better way to handle this I'm all ears.

```
//Returns: friend record ID or null
Future<String?> getFriendDocID(String friendUsername) async {
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final friendQuerySnapshot = await firestore.collection(usersCollection).doc(currentUID).collection(friendsCollection).where('username', isEqualTo: friendUsername).limit(1).get();

if (friendQuerySnapshot.size == 0) {
  return null;
}

var friendDocID;

friendQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
  friendDocID = element.id;
});

return friendDocID;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
final friendRecordExists = getFriendDocID(friendUsername);

if (friendRecordExists == null) { // The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
  //...
}
```

Comment: You should await future to get the return value.

Comment: @Soliev yup I realized that shortly after I submitted the post lol...feel free to write it as an answer and I'll mark you as correct!

Answer (score 1):

the function is returning **future** so you should use **await** for getting the response.

```
final friendRecordExists = await getFriendDocID(friendUsername);

if (friendRecordExists == null) { // The operand can't be null, so the 
  //...
}
```